# Thread Weaver InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, junit, easymock, thread-weaver

I'm trying to get Thread Weaver to work but no matter what I try I always get the exception below.

I create a clean project with only EasyMock, JUnit and Thread Weaver in it, and the code is the example from the Thread Weaver documentation (I'm using EasyMock 4.2 and I tried it with JDK 15 and JDK 9 and JUnit 4 and JUnit 5).

Any idea anyone...?

Class tested:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList extends ArrayList {
    synchronized public boolean  putIfAbsent(Object o) {
        boolean absent = !super.contains(o);
        if (absent) {
            super.add(o);
        }
        return absent;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
import com.google.testing.threadtester.*;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MyListTest  {

    private MyList list;

    @Test
    public void testThreading() {
        AnnotatedTestRunner runner = new AnnotatedTestRunner();
        // Run all Weaver tests in this class, using MyList as the Class Under Test.
        runner.runTests(this.getClass(), MyList.class);
    }

    @ThreadedBefore
    public void before() {
        list = new MyList();
    }

    @ThreadedMain
    public void mainThread() {
        list.putIfAbsent("A");
    }

    @ThreadedSecondary
    public void secondThread() {
        list.putIfAbsent("A");
    }

    @ThreadedAfter
    public void after() {
        assertEquals(1, list.size());
    }
}
```

The Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at com.google.testing.threadtester.MethodCaller.invoke(MethodCaller.java:71)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.BaseThreadedTestRunner.runTests(BaseThreadedTestRunner.java:210)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.BaseThreadedTestRunner.runTests(BaseThreadedTestRunner.java:174)
    at MyListTest.testThreading(MyListTest.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.MethodCaller.invoke(MethodCaller.java:68)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instrument class
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.TestInstrumenter.instrument(TestInstrumenter.java:446)
    at com.google.testing.instrumentation.InstrumentedClassLoader.findClass(InstrumentedClassLoader.java:138)
    at com.google.testing.instrumentation.InstrumentedClassLoader.loadClass(InstrumentedClassLoader.java:114)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.AnnotatedTestWrapper.runTests(AnnotatedTestWrapper.java:272)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: com.google.testing.threadtester.CallLogger
    at javassist.CtField.make(CtField.java:167)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.TestInstrumenter.addDeclaration(TestInstrumenter.java:501)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.TestInstrumenter.processClass(TestInstrumenter.java:470)
    at com.google.testing.threadtester.TestInstrumenter.instrument(TestInstrumenter.java:444)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: compile error: no such class: com.google.testing.threadtester.CallLogger
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:468)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:412)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByJvmName(MemberResolver.java:319)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:336)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:323)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileField(Javac.java:133)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compile(Javac.java:93)
    at javassist.CtField.make(CtField.java:162)
    ... 38 more
```

EDIT:

To clarify - the library is there and the project compiles. The error only happens when I actually run the tests

[image]

Comment: the exception is telling you what's wrong ... this class `Caused by: compile error: no such class: com.google.testing.threadtester.CallLogger` is missing ??  In my testing I normally get InvocationTargetExceptions with JUnit when something unexpected (e.g. a runtime exception) gets thrown.  So in this case maybe a classpath issue / missing library??

Comment: The library is there. I will add the pom.xml and a screenshot to make it clearer.

Comment: @traveh did you resolve this issue? The same error occurs for me...

Comment: It seems to be a bug with `javassist` and there's no workaround apparently as described in this thread. The thread is pretty old (2010) and not sure if it has been fixed after that. But I still get this error even today.
[thread-weaver-javassist-bug](https://groups.google.com/g/thread-weaver/c/Tww7vUgoODQ?pli=1)